# Android: Drag View outside screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have an activity where users can drag and drop around some buttons.
All my draggable views are inside a `RelativeLayout` and to drag them around I change their top and left margins.
Everything works perfect, except that when I drag the views close to the right and bottom edge of the screen, they shrink instead of being drawn outside the screen.
Is there any way for having the same behaviour on the all edges of the screen (currently only works fine on the top and left edge).

I guess I can have a left and top negative margin. But when I have `left margin > screen width` or `top margin > screen height` the images shrink.

Answer (score 1):

To implement custom positioning of views inside a `ViewGroup` the best way is to implement your custom `ViewGroup` overriding `onLayout()`.

It is not that difficult and I explained how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31484079/913286). (the question is newer and has more visibility)

**Edit**:
You might also want to look into the Drag and Drop Api [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html). Thanks to Zainodis for the comment.

Comment: What bugs me about this: Android provides Drag & Drop functionality, so would it not make sense to provide a view that can actually handle drag & drop without distorting the draggable views...? Instead of everyone having to re-invent the wheel.